# Error building blackbox exporter

Tags: prometheus

I am absolutely new to Prometheus and currently trying to troubleshoot the error that is being reflected while building blackbox exporter (https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter).

```
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# pwd
/usr/local/blackbox_exporter
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# echo $GOROOT
/usr/local/go/default
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# echo $GOPATH
/usr/local/blackbox_exporter
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# make
>> formatting code
can't load package: package _/usr/local/blackbox_exporter: cannot find package "_/usr/local/blackbox_exporter" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/_/usr/local/blackbox_exporter (from $GOROOT)
    /usr/local/blackbox_exporter/src/_/usr/local/blackbox_exporter (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [format] Error 1
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

`go` looks in the `src`subfolder of `$GOPATH` when building the executable. See https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH for documentation about this. I was able to build the executable using `make`, but `go install` requires fewer steps.

These steps worked for me:

```
export GOPATH=/usr/local/go
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src
cd $GOPATH/src
git clone https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter.git
cd blackbox_exporter
go install
```

If no errors are encountered, the executable should be located at `$GOPATH/bin/blackbox_exporter`. The executable needs to be able to find `blackbox.yml`, which is in `$GOPATH/src/blackbox_exporter`. I ran the executable using:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/blackbox_exporter
$GOPATH/bin/blackbox_exporter
```

Comment: @SethDifiey
i exported the GOPATH as specified. Created the src directory inside GOPATH and cloned the blackbox exporter in it.

`[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# pwd
/usr/local/go/default/src/blackbox_exporter
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# make
>> formatting code
package bytes: directory "/usr/local/go/default/src/bytes" is not using a known version control system
package errors: directory "/usr/local/go/default/src/errors" is not using a known version control system
...
make: *** [promu] Error 1`

Comment: Please use `go install` instead of `make` and tell me what happens. Make sure you are in the folder `$GOPATH/src/blackbox_exporter` when you run `go install`

Comment: This is the result.  
  
`[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# pwd
/usr/local/go/default/src/blackbox_exporter
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# go install
import cycle not allowed
package blackbox_exporter
 imports bufio
 imports bytes
 imports errors
 imports runtime
 imports runtime/internal/atomic
 imports unsafe
 imports runtime
import cycle not allowed
package blackbox_exporter
 imports crypto/tls
 imports crypto/x509
 imports net
 imports runtime/cgo
 imports runtime/cgo`

Comment: Unless there is something you need to keep in your `$GOPATH` folder, I recommend deleting your `$GOPATH` folder and all of its contents and then following the list of commands exactly as I put them in the answer

Comment: What is the version Go are you using? I did a fresh install of go1.6.2 and still getting the same error. These are my environment variables. 
`[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# echo $GOROOT
/usr/local/go/default
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# echo $GOPATH
/usr/local/go/default`

Comment: If it helps, I did not set `GOROOT`. I am using version 1.6.2 of go. Yes, I have just confirmed that if I set `GOROOT=$GOPATH`, `go install` fails. Unset `GOROOT` with `export GOROOT=`

Comment: i unset GOROOT. To confirm i did a printenv and only the GOPATH is being reflected. Ran go install from $GOPATH/src/blackbox_exporter. Still the same error.

Comment: What is the result of running `which go`?

Comment: /usr/local/go/default/bin/go

Comment: OK, change your GOPATH to something other than `/usr/local/go`. How about `~/gopath`. Replace `/usr/local/go` in the answer's instructions with `~/gopath`. With this replacement, run the instructions again.

Comment: `[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# echo $GOPATH
/root/gopath
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# pwd
/root/gopath/src/blackbox_exporter
[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# go install
tcp.go:17:2: cannot find package "bufio" in any of:
 /root/gopath/src/blackbox_exporter/vendor/bufio (vendor tree)
 /usr/local/go/src/bufio (from $GOROOT)
 /root/gopath/src/bufio (from $GOPATH)
icmp.go:17:2: cannot find package "bytes" in any of:
 /root/gopath/src/blackbox_exporter/vendor/bytes (vendor tree)
 /usr/local/go/src/bytes (from $GOROOT)
 /root/gopath/src/bytes (from $GOPATH)
`

Comment: It looks like `GOROOT` is set again. Please unset `GOROOT` using `export GOROOT=` Running `echo $GOROOT` should return a blank line

Comment: [root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# echo $GOROOT

[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# printenv | grep GO
GOPATH=/root/gopath

Comment: You may have installed `go` in a non-standard location. Try `export GOROOT=/usr/local/go` as you had it before, and with `export GOPATH=/root/gopath`

Comment: Ok, now a different error shows up 
`[root@sk004 blackbox_exporter]# go install
panic: runtime error: slice bounds out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x93d400, 0xc82000e0a0)
 /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:481 +0x3e6
main.vendoredImportPath(0xc820135c00, 0xc8201ed7a1, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0)
 /usr/local/go/src/cmd/go/pkg.go:466 +0x713
main.loadImport(0xc8201ed7a1, 0x20, 0xc8204fb9e0, 0x58, 0xc820135c00, 0xc8201b7688, 0xc8201ed8f0, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, ...)
 /usr/local/go/src/cmd/go/pkg.go:336 +0xe52
main.(*Package).load(0xc820135c00, 0xc8201b7688, 0xc82024c000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4)
...
`

Comment: If I have another idea, I will add it to the comments or the answer. As of now, I am not sure what is going on. In the stacktrace you pasted with the `panic runtime error` message, the last few lines of the stack trace might be more helpful for debugging than the first few lines.

Comment: When following those above instructions, I am also running into some (different) errors:
`go install
main.go:26:2: cannot find package "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus" in any of:
 /usr/src/pkg/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus (from $GOROOT)
 /home/me/gopath/src/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus (from $GOPATH)`
My GOPATH being: ~/gopath and GOROOT returning a blank line.

Comment: ... My mistake, the relevant packages were not imported with go get

Comment: @DavidB. did the instructions work for you after the relevant packages were imported? How can the instructions be improved?

Comment: @SethDifley yes it worked at the end thanks. Maybe listing the packages could help? `github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus`, `github.com/Sirupsen/logrus`, `golang.org/x/net/icmp` and `gopkg.in/yaml.v2`.
I have to say I'm really getting started with Go so this is pretty new to me. 
Also worth mentioning that I am using Go version 1.6 linux/amd64.

Comment: how can i refer it to correct packages
`main.go:18:2: cannot find package "context" in any of:
 /root/go/src/blackbox_exporter/vendor/context (vendor tree)
 /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/context (from $GOROOT)
 /root/go/src/context (from $GOPATH)
main.go:40:2: cannot find package "github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/config" in any of:
 /root/go/src/blackbox_exporter/vendor/github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/config (vendor tree)
 /usr/lib/go-1.6/src/github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/config (from $GOROOT)
 /root/go/src/github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/config (from $GOPATH)`

Answer (score 1):

Ran into same error and none of the answers worked; solved it by:

```
$go version
go version go1.7 linux/amd64

$go get github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter
$go build github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter
```