# Error when building the blackbox_exporter Docker image

Tags: docker, monitoring, prometheus

I am just getting started with [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) and I may be doing something wrong, but I am getting the following error when trying to build the blackbox_exporter (https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter) image with:

```
docker build -t blackbox_exporter .
```

Error being:

```
Step 3 : COPY blackbox_exporter /bin/blackbox_exporter
lstat blackbox_exporter: no such file or directory
```

When I edit the Dockerfile and update it to:

```
COPY . /bin/blackbox_exporter
```

Then it builds properly. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [Makefile for that project](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter/blob/master/Makefile), the docker image build happens after the application is built by promu. The container is designed to be a minimal environment of busybox and the application binary that you first create outside of docker.

Comment: Thanks! I am now running into a GOPATH error:
`make
>> formatting code
can't load package: package _/home/me/monitoring/blackbox_exporter: cannot find package "_/home/me/monitoring/blackbox_exporter" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/_/home/me/monitoring/blackbox_exporter (from $GOROOT)
 /home/me/monitoring/blackbox_exporter/src/_/home/me/monitoring/blackbox_exporter (from $GOPATH)
make: *** [format] Error 1`

Comment: ... Actually it looks like someone else ran into this error:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637936/error-building-blackbox-exporter/37638471#37638471